# JSS nested styles container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm working with the React Material UI    -> [TextField](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/) component and I want to make some wrapper around it with the possibility to override the styles.
According the documentation we have a 2 props to achieve this:
1) InputProps - Here we should pass *classes* into the inner [Input](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/) component which is core of our TextField.
2) direct *classes* property which should be applied to the TextField directly. And that classes should contains rules for the [FormControl](https://material-ui-next.com/api/form-control/)

(sounds hard, actually it is when you are working with the Material UI =) )

anyway, I want to do something like this

```
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

export const TextInputCSSCreator = theme => ({
    "FormControlClasses" : {
        "root" : { "color" : "red }
       }
    "InputClasses" : {
       "underline" : {
           "&:after" : {
               backgroundColor : "red",
           },
       }
    }

});

<TextField
                classses={this.props.classes.FormControlClasses}
                id={this.props.id}
                InputProps={{
                    classes : this.props.classes.InputClasses
                }}
                label={this.props.label}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this._onValueChange}
                margin={this.props.margin}
            />

export default withStyles(TextInputCSSCreator)(TextInput);
```

Here I wanted to have a possibility to pass a whole object into my 2 targets. Input and FormControl. 
But here is the main issue and I don't know how to resolve it. It looks like JSS (it's the same withStyles from MaterialUi)  doesn't work with the object which contains nested containers for the rules.

I've done this task via this ugly way. It looks like HELL but I didn't find any way how to avoid it. Could someone help me, please? Is it really only one way to accomplish this requirement?

Cause the way which I want to implement provide us flexibility, we might add any classes that we want at any time, when at the second way (below) we have to hardcode all possible classes at the start

Btw. I want to provide a mechanism to change the styles of my components from outer application so that's why I can't use CSS cause at the output it should be valid commonJS module.

```
export const TextInputCSSCreator = theme => ({
    "FormControlRoot" : {},
    "FormControlMarginNormal" : {},
    "FormControlMarginDense" : {},
    "FormControlFullWidth" : {},

    "InputRoot" : {},
    "InputFormControl" : {},
    "InputFocused" : {},
    "InputDisabled" : {},
    "InputUnderline" : {
        "&:after" : {
            backgroundColor : "red",
        },
    },
    "InputError" : {},
    "InputMultiline" : {},
    "InputFullWIdth" : {},
    "InputInput" : {},
    "InputInputMarginDense" : {},
    "InputInputDisabled" : {},
    "InputInputMultiline" : {},
    "InputInputType" : {},
    "InputInputTypeSearch" : {}
});

render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (

            <TextField
                classes={{
                    root : classes.FormControlRoot,
          marginNormal : classes.FormControlMarginNormal,
                    marginDense : classes.FormControlMarginDense,
                    fullWidth : classes.FormControlFullWidth,
                }}
                id={this.props.id}
                InputProps={{
                    classes : {
                        root : classes.InputRoot,
                        formControl : classes.InputFormControl,
                        focused : classes.InputFocused,
                        disabled : classes.InputDisabled,
                        underline : classes.InputUnderline,
                        error : classes.InputError,
                        multiline : classes.InputMultiline,
                        fullWidth : classes.InputFullWIdth,
                        input : classes.InputInput,
                        inputMarginDense : classes.InputInputMarginDense,
                        inputDisabled : classes.InputInputDisabled,
                        inputMultiline : classes.InputInputMultiline,
                        inputType : classes.InputInputType,
                        inputTypeSearch : classes.InputInputTypeSearch
                    }
                }}
                label={this.props.label}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this._onValueChange}
                margin={this.props.margin}
            />


        );
    }

export default withStyles(TextInputCSSCreator)(TextInput);
```

Answer (score 2):

what I would do in this situation is to create theme for this component in separate file with createMuiTheme({}) and apply it to component with MuiTheme provider component. 
Exp:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiInput: {
            root:{
                color: 'red',
            },
            underline: {
                    '&:after': {
                      backgroundColor: '#000000',
                    }
              },
        },
    }

});
export default customTheme;
```

and then use it on my component like this:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme = {customTheme}>
[Your component]
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the answer. But what if I want to have a few components which should look different than others which are controlled by theme?

Comment: You can use different themes for different components, I tested it with having App.js wrapped in <MuiThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}> and one of child components wrapped in its own customTheme. In that case the child component had only styles that where provided with customTheme without inheriting anything from globalTheme.

Comment: But it looks like an overhead to wrap every component into their own Theme Provider. I guess it reduces app performance, probably, isnt it?

Comment: I would use this approach if I have one global theme that takes care of most of my needs, and maybe, if I need like a special dialog, I would create its own theme and save it. Now I wouldn't abuse it to the point where every component will have its own theme, certain things could be changed with classes and styles etc. As far as performance, that's something that needs to be tested, from my understanding it shouldn't be much worse than rewriting styles withStyles() every time.