# How do I override a style of a deeply nested component? (Material-UI Jss Styling)

Tags: material-ui, jss

Material UI TextField is rendered to the following DOM structure:

```
<FormControl... > 
    <BaseInput ...>
        <input class ="MuiInputBase-input-29" ...>
    </BaseInput>
</FormControl>
```

If I put anything into TextField's 'className' or 'classes' or 'style', it all goes to FormControl.

What I want is to override style "MuiInputBase-input-29". Specifically I need to change font-size, and also some other stylings.

The only option I found is this: [JSS nested styles container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631901/jss-nested-styles-container)

but it's

1. effectivly disables global theme for my components (which I don't
   want to),
2. additional overhead

Is there a way to override this ("MuiInputBase-input-29") deep style in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you still need answer, I've already find a solution

You can set a parameter InputProps to Text field. Here is my InputProps:

```
InputProps={{
  classes: {
    root: multiline ? classes.inputRootMultiline : null,
    input: classNames(
      classes.modalTextResize,
      classes.modalInputPadding,
      disabled && disabledValue ? classes.disabled : classes.modalTextColor,
    ),
  },
}}
```

Where 'input' are classes for input element and 'root' are classes for MuiInputBase

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but maybe something like this (exact nesting css classes set for your case):

```
import './styles.css';


styles.css:
-------------------------------
.container  .children {
      color: red;
}
```

Comment: No, the question is about Jss. Your example is about sass or similar, not applicable for jss